# Formula about Closure of Sets

Tags: general-topology

I am reading the proof in [link here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2601983/800888) in which I found a formula confusing.

It says that ${\rm Cl}_X(W_0\cap A)={\rm Cl}_X(W_0\cap{\rm Cl}_X(A))$ due to $W_0$ is open.

One direction ${\rm Cl}_X(W_0\cap A)\subseteq{\rm Cl}_X(W_0\cap{\rm Cl}_X(A))$ is trivial, but another direction seems not clear to me.

In particular, the author mentions that this holds because $W_0$ is open. What is the role of $W_0$ here?

I am confused about this formula. Hope anyone have good ideas on this.

> **Solution.** Inspired by the following answer, I have come up with a proof of that: For each $x\in{\rm Cl}_X(W_0\cap{\rm Cl}_X(A))$, let $U$ be an arbitrary neighborhood of $x$. Then
> $$U\cap(W_0\cap{\rm Cl}_X(A))=(U\cap W_0)\cap{\rm Cl}_X(A)\ne\emptyset.$$
> As we can see, for each $y\in U\cap W_0\cap{\rm Cl}_X(A)\subseteq{\rm Cl}_X(A)$, since $U\cap W_0$ is a neighborhood of $y$ (That is where the openness of $W_0$ is used!), it follows that
> $$(U\cap W_0)\cap A=U\cap(W_0\cap A)\neq\emptyset.$$
> Thus, we have $x\in{\rm Cl}_X(W_0\cap A)$, completing the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Suppose that $X=\mathbb R$ equipped with standard metric $|\cdot |$.

Let $y\in Cl_X(W_0\cap Cl_X(A))$. Then, there is a sequence $(x_n)$ of $W_0\cap Cl_X(A)$ that converges to $y$. Since $(x_n)$ is in $Cl_X(A)$, there is a sequence $(x_{m}^n)_m$ in $A$ that converges to $x_n$. Since $x_m^n\to x^n$ when $m\to \infty $ and $W_0\ni x_n$ is open, there is $m_n\geq n$ s.t. $$|x_{m_n}^n-x_n|<\frac{1}{n}\quad \text{and}\quad x_{m_n}^n\in W_0,$$ for all $n$. Finally, $(x_{m_n}^n)$ is a sequence of $W_0\cap A$ that converges to $y$. Therefore $y\in Cl_X(W_0\cap A)$ as wished.

---

**Edit**

This proof can be very easily adapted to more abstract spaces. But since the question was rather on the necessity of $W_0$ to be open than on a topological proof of this statement, I put this answer as a Hint.

Comment: Thanks. This proof is nice, but it would be better if you use arguments in topology rather than in analysis.

Comment: @BernardPan: I let you adapt the proof ;-) But your question was rather on the necessity of $W_0$ beeing open than on a topological proof of the result (if I'm not mistaken). So, the best way to see it is in a simple case, for example when $X=\mathbb R$ equipped with the standard metric. Nevertheless, this proof can be very easily adapted on more abstract spaces.

Comment: Thanks. I have written a proof in general form. Could you please help me check if it is valid?

Comment: @BernardPan: Yes your proof is very good.